# How to make list double every other term, and add 2 digit numbers?

Tags: python, list

```
numbers = raw_input("Enter numbers: ")
numbers = [numbers]
numbers = list(numbers[0])
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]
numbers[::2] = [2*x for x in numbers[::2]]
for x in numbers: #code stops working as i want here
    if x == 10:
        x = 1
    elif x == 12:
        x = 3
    elif x == 14:
        x = 5
    elif x == 16:
        x = 7
    elif x == 18:
        x = 9
print(numbers)
```

Basically I want it to take the numbers I give it, put it into a list, split that list, change all elements in the list to integers, and for every other element in the list, double it, and (here's where it stops working) take the possible 2 digit numbers from doubling 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9 and add the digits.

I think the for, if, and elif statements are right but I think their bodies are wrong. What do I do to change x if it's not like a variable? (x = 1)

Or am I doing the last step all wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You can't change the variable indicating an item in a collection due to loop scope.

Comment: An easier way to add digits would be: `sum(map(int, str(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `x = 1` is simply *rebinding* the name `x` to the value `1`. This does **not** modify the contents of `numbers`.

If you want to change a value contained in a list you must explicitly do so by using:

```
numbers[index] = value
```

For example:

```
for i, x in enumerate(numbers):
    if x >= 10: # not actually required: 0<= x < 10 implies x%10 == x and x//10 == 0
        numbers[i] = x%10 + x//10
```

Note that if you have a two digit number then `x % 10` is equal to the first digit while `x // 10` (integer division/quotient) is equal to the second digit.

In fact you could even do:

```
numbers[i] = sum(divmod(x, 10))
```

Comment: It works. I understand in a for loop that `for x in list:` makes every element (every x) in the list (list) do something, but what does `for i, x in ...:` do? What's the difference/purpose of 2 names (i and x)?

Comment: @JacobWheeler See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops . Also you may be interested in "tuple unpacking" (just google for it).

Comment: @JacobWheeler `enumerate` returns pairs containing an index and a value corresponding with `i` and `x`

Comment: So i is the index and x is the actual element?

Comment: And enumerate() applies indexes to the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the variable indicating an item in a collection due to loop scope. Try this instead:

```
for i, x in enumerate(numbers): 
    numbers[i] = sum(map(int, str(x)))
```

Comment: Basically the `x` in the loop header is different from the `x` reference in the loop itself.

Comment: So it's if you turn all int into str how does it sum strings?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: `map(a, b)` applies all b to a, so in this case it does str(x) to all int. So if everything is a string, how can `sum` sum strings? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: So `enumerate` turns all elements in numbers to strings, and then you turn them all back to integers with `map`?

Comment: So `enumerate` makes all the elements in the list strings?

Comment: `map` takes this index and value from `enumerate` to obtain a sum from the sum of the value's digits and it is reassigned according to the index.

Comment: @JacobWheeler Do you understand now?

Comment: I don't understand what str(x) is for.

Comment: `str` casts the passed integer `x` to a string or a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):
    if x in (10, 12, 14, 16, 18):
        return x-9
    else return x
```

Instead of the loop at the end,

```
numbers = [f(n) for n in numbers]
```

Of course, you can put the definition of f in the list comprehension, but it starts looking a bit cramped.